# Laplace equation in polar coordinate

Tags: partial-differential-equations

\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\Delta u = 0}\\
{u = V;r = b}\\
{u + \frac{{Va\sin n\theta }}{{r(\log b - \log a)}} = 0;r = a}
\end{array}
I want to solve the above Laplace's equation in polar coordinates at a cyclic disk:

In this case, it helps to solve the problem by solving for $\tilde{\phi} = \phi - V$. Write the solution as an expansion of the eigenfunctions of the spatial Laplace operator. i.e. use separation of variables,$$ \tilde{\phi}(r,\theta) = A_o \ln r + B_o + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n \cos(n \theta) + B_n \sin(n \theta)) (C_n r^n + D_n r^{-n}) $$ But at $r = b, \tilde{\phi} = 0 \Longrightarrow D_n = - b^{2n} C_n$. Absorbing $C_n$ into the other constants, we have

$$ \tilde{\phi}(r,\theta) = A_o \ln r + B_o + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n \cos(n \theta) + B_n \sin(n \theta)) ( r^n - b^{2n} r^{-n}) $$

Comment: Wikipedia has it, in the article, "Laplace operator": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Two_dimensions

Comment: @Travis Thanks! I know what Laplace operator in polar coordinate is. I don't know how to deal with the boundary conditions.

Comment: What is your question? Have you solved it?